# How to create credintals of SignalR client

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I try to create credintals or claims by different way to SignalR client, for example this way

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(URL, opt => opt.Headers.Add("Bearer", myJWT)).
        WithAutomaticReconnect(new[] { TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) }).
        Build();
```

But in my server hub I don't see anything in my Hub in this callback

```
public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
```

Connection established normally, I see it but in "Connect" object and "hubContext" object don't see anymore (user, headers, identity) its empty.
I have no special security configuration of my SignalR service, I have configure only SignalR endpoint, but I would expect to see at least client headers in my server hub, but no.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that in `OnConnectedAsync` method by using this property:

```
Context.GetHttpContext().Request
```

And just a heads up, you want to do authorization header like this:

```
opt.Headers.Add("Authorization", myJWT)
```

Then grab it like this:

```
var token = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```